# Wrong number of database records is output by a Java program

Tags: java, sql, mysql, database

I have a table in mySQL and has 3 line which has name ,address,Telephone,Age,Charge. in two of them the names are "Adam" and the last row is "Abas" ,i don't know that why it prints in the console like this,please help me thanks!

```
      Statement s;
    int s4,s5;String s1,s2,s3;
    List<InfoClass> clientList = null;
    try {
        s = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE Name LIKE 'A%'");
        InfoClass list = null;

        while (rs.next()) {
            s1 = rs.getString(2);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s1 = null;
            }
            s2 = rs.getString(3);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s2 = null;
            }

            s3 = rs.getString(4);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s3 = null;
            }
              s4 = rs.getInt(5);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s4 = 0;
            }
            s5 = rs.getInt(6);
            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                s5 = 0;
            }





            list = new InfoClass(s1, s2);

            if (clientList == null) {
                clientList = new ArrayList<InfoClass>();
            }

            clientList.add(list);





        }
       for(int i=0;i<clientList.size();i++){
           InfoClass c =clientList.get(i);
           System.out.println(c.getName());


        }
```

in the console:

```
run:
Adam Smit
Adam Smit
Abas
Adam Smit
Adam Smit
Adam Smit
Adam Smit
```

I want the output be like this:

```
  run:
Adam Smit
Adam Smit
Abas
```

Comment: Your question is extremely confused. Please post the table structure, and the contents of the table. Also, please ask a specific question. What output did you expect? What part surprises you? Without a specific question, your question entry will be closed quickly.

Comment: Does the select query returns the same number of rows as program? This will help you to find whether the problem is with the query or with the program

Comment: This code will throw a NullPointerException if nothing matches your select criteria because you are lazily constructing `clientList`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a customer named 'Abas' in your database, which is a valid match for your query.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the rs.getString( String columnLabel ) method.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please change the `println` row into this:

```
System.out.println("" + i + ": " + c.getName());
```

and run it?

Comment: `@Johanna`: what does it output?